# Text Box to accept all values in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have wrote a program for arithmetic operations. Results are working fine.
But I would like to go ahead a bit.
I want a text box, that accepts all values like Positive, Negative Values, Decimal Values (Int, Float, Long, Double) excpet String or Character.
While String or Character is entered, it should throw an error message (i will do it in Message box with try & Catch)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int num1, num2, res;
num1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
num2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
res = num1 * num2;
textBox3.Text = (num1 * num2).ToString();
}
```

Comment: `NumericUpDown` accepts all values like Positive, Negative Values, Decimal Values (Int, Float, Long, Double) except String or Character. MessageBoxes which interrupt typing are evil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TryParse`, change `num1` and `num2` types for the most general one (`double`):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // double as the most general numeric type
  double num1, num2;

  if (!double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num1)) {
    if (textBox1.CanFocus) 
      textBox1.Focus();

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("\"{0}\" is not a valid value", textBox1.Text));
  } 
  else if (!double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out num2)) {
    if (textBox2.CanFocus) 
      textBox2.Focus();

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("\"{0}\" is not a valid value", textBox2.Text));
  }
  else
    textBox3.Text = (num1 * num2).ToString();
}
```

Comment: what if the person enter a '0' intentionally?

Comment: @gayan1991: well, `0` will be converted into `double` while, `'0'` (with apostrophes) will *not* be converted and `'0' is not a valid value` message will be shown

Comment: Yeah 0 does not make sense in multiplications but as a programmer you should be able to accept 0 as it is a result none the less, but depends on the rules.

Comment: i get a error.
`The name 'ShowMessage' doesn't exist in the current context`

Comment: @Sheik M: sorry for type, should be `MessageBox.Show`

Comment: @gayan1991: And I do accept `0`, or `0.0`, or `0e1`, or `-0` and whatever numeric format; what I reject is *character* `'0'`

Comment: Done @DmitryBychenko.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You are not allowing user to type 0, is that right?

Comment: @gayan1991: I allow user to type `0`, since `0` is just a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch, and use your variable as float so that you can free to input float and int data in textbox input

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    float num1, num2, res;
    try
          {
             num1 = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
          }
        catch (Exception)
          {
             MessageBox.Show("Error");       
          }
        try
          {
             num2 = float.Parse(textBox2.Text);
          }
        catch (Exception)
          {
             MessageBox.Show("Error");      
          }
    res = num1 * num2;
    textBox3.Text = (num1 * num2).ToString();
  }
```

Comment: This won't handle floats, only integers.

Comment: ok I am editing, if you want that user input float then you can directly parse it float instead int because you can store int in a float, so its ok to input in a one variable then calculate it as wish